# Writing a boolean matrix to a string

Tags: r, matrix

I have a lower triangular matrix containing TRUE/FALSE values. The matrix is created from a `pairwise.t.test` and a comparison to the acceptable p-value (p<0.05 => TRUE).

I am trying to output the matrix true values in a string according to a specific formatting without using a mess of `if` conditions. My thoughts were on matrix products/sums to achieve it, but there may be no elegant solution. If you think it's impossible to do it, I would like to know it aswell so I don't hit my head on the wall forever

**The formatting:**

- If a pair of values (ex:1,2) are TRUE, we output it as "1≠2".
- If a value is TRUE with multiple values (ex: 1 with 2,3), we output it as "1≠2,3".
- If a value is TRUE with everyone(ex:1 with 2,3,4) we use the word "all" => output is "1≠all"
- If  2 pairs (ex:1,2 and 3,4) are TRUE, we separate them with a space. output is "1≠2 3≠4"
- If everything is TRUE, we output "all≠"

As of now, I am doing it manually so I don't really have any code to show. I am open to any ideas :)

**Examples:**

```
     1    2     3
2  TRUE   NA    NA
3  TRUE TRUE    NA
4  TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

The string for this matrix would be `"1,2≠all"` because 1 and 2 are true with everyone.

```
     1    2     3
2  FALSE  NA    NA
3  TRUE TRUE    NA
4  TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

The string for this matrix would be `"1,2≠3,4` because 1 is true with 3,4 and 2 is true with 3,4.

Test matrices:

```
mTest = matrix(c(T,T,T,NA,F,T,NA,NA,F),nrow=3,ncol=3) # "1≠all 2≠3"
row.names(mTest) <- c(2,3,4)  ; colnames(mTest) <- c(1,2,3) 
mTest[] = c(T,F,T,NA,F,T,NA,NA,F) # "1≠2 1,2≠4"
mTest[] = c(T,T,T,NA,T,F,NA,NA,T) # "1,3≠all"
```

Comment: Your second example seems inconsistent: `mtx[1,1]` is false, though you say *"1 and 2 are true with everyone"*. Can you clarify?

Comment: Edited it, i should really stop copy/pasting

Comment: I've got to admit, @Oligg, though I can see some of what you are trying to do, I cannot see how this language of summarizing can be used effectively. The logic of creating that possibly-grouped summary can get rather complex, and given larger matrices it will scale poorly. This may be a time when a small example like this would benefit from more detail and context, namely: *ultimately, how are you using this kind of summary*. (I hope this isn't Pandora's Box!)

Comment: It's used to show significal differences between cluster means. The goal is to summarize it in a single column as it is going in a scientific article.. and the less it takes space the better it is.